# c# unity2d on window open prevent user from being able to interact with the background

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for some guidance on how to go about my question.  Basically, I have a few `GUI.Button` with one of them being a "Filter" button.  When I click the "Filter" button, it opens a `GUI.Window` on a part of the screen.  However, I want the buttons in the background to be unable to be interacted with while the window is open.  Are there any functions that could help me with this?  I couldn't seem to find one.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add full-screen box collider to scene and cover all the background components until your GUI window is closed.

Comment: Follow-up question:                                                                                      I created a full-screen box collider called "Blocker" and tried kept it SetActive(false) until I pressed the filter button, upon which it would make the "Blocker" game object SetActive(true) and then create the filter window.  That way I was hoping it would block the current screen contents but not the filter window since it was called afterwards. However...that didn't seem to work.  Any ideas?